# Take class string and add inline css with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the next output code:

```
<div class="post-term">
  <a href="/term/1" class="color-cc0000">historical</a>
</div>

<div class="post-term">
  <a href="/term/2" class="color-999999">historical</a>
</div>
```

How to take string after "color-" in class attribute and add css background-color inline style?

The resulting code should be:

```
<div class="post-term">
  <a href="/term/1" style="background-color: #cc0000">historical</a>
</div>

<div class="post-term">
  <a href="/term/2" style="background-color: #999999">historical</a>
</div>
```

I'm using Drupal Views so just can add css class attribute to target string with Javascript.

The problem with different codes I tried is that only changes correctly the first class and the next ones just drop the string. Let me explain better in the next resulting output code:

```
<div class="post-term">
  <a href="/term/1" style="background-color: #cc0000">historical</a>
</div>

<div class="post-term">
  <a href="/term/2" class="color-">historical</a>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: That's not what classes are for. You should probably use a `data-` attribute.

Comment: I'm using Drupal Views, It only allows add class attribute.

Comment: Why did you prefer the jQuery answer when you could pick a non-jQuery one as well?

Comment: Hi @connexo. I chose both but Jquery answer was the last one and it was the one that remained. I didn't know only can choose one right answer. Honestly, Jquery answer is nicer to me and Drupal uses Jquery, but question was about Javascript so your answer is the one that best fits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beforehand: As @wizzwizz4 mentioned, you're misusing the css class attribute here. It'd be better to declare that as a data-attribute.

Fetch your link elements using `document.querySelectorAll` and an appropriate CSS selector, iterate over the array you create from the nodelist you're getting and set the background-color programmatically like this:

```js
const postlinks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.post-term a'));

for (const postlink of postlinks) {
  postlink.style.backgroundColor = `#${postlink.className.split('-')[1]}`;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-term">
  <a href="/term/1" class="color-cc0000">historical</a>
</div>

<div class="post-term">
  <a href="/term/2" class="color-999999">historical</a>
</div>

<div class="post-term">
  <a href="/term/1" class="color-00cc00">historical</a>
</div>

<div class="post-term">
  <a href="/term/2" class="color-0000cc">historical</a>
</div>

<div class="post-term">
  <a href="/term/1" class="color-000000">historical</a>
</div>

<div class="post-term">
  <a href="/term/2" class="color-dddddd">historical</a>
</div>
```

If you want to remove the class attribute (like your target code suggests), add the following line inside the `for .. of` loop:

```
postlink.removeAttribute('class');
```

Comment: Your code works well but I don't know why drop the color code after "color-" after the first class change. Please, see question update. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It works for any number of links, I've just added some to the sample code here. I have no clue as of why you're getting the result you added to your post. Which browser are you observing that in?

Comment: I'm testing on Firefox, Chrome and Edge. I think is a Drupal issue but I don't understand how is it possible because last week was working well with a Javascript code that I removed by mistake :(

Answer (score 1):

Though, it is a good practice to use `data-attributes` for storing such data, you can do it using class attribute as well

```js
$('.post-term a').each(function(){
 $(this).css('background-color','#'+$(this).attr('class').split('-')[1]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-term">
  <a href="/term/1" class="color-cc0000" data-color='cc0000'>historical</a>
</div>

<div class="post-term">
  <a href="/term/2" class="color-999999" data-color='999999'>historical</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using Drupal Views, It only allows add class attribute.

Comment: @Bahsite in that case, here you go

Comment: Your code works well and looks pretty narrow to me, but I don't know why drop the color code after the first "color-" class change. Please, see question update. Thanks a lot Sangram.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have not just `color-999999` in a class, but `color-999999 foo` or `foo color-999999` and the parent name is not `.post-term` every time

```js
var aElements = $("a").filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr("class").match(/color\-/);
});

$.each(aElements, function(index,el){
 let col = el.getAttribute("class").match(/color\-[a-z0-9]{6}/)[0].split("-")[1];
        el.setAttribute("style", "background-color: #" + col + ";");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-term">
  <a href="/term/1" class="color-cc0000 foo">historical</a>
</div>

<div class="post-term">
  <a href="/term/2" class="foo color-999999">historical</a>
</div>
```